# Comment flagging limit reached, but dialog still appears?

Tags: discussion, bug, comment-flags

I noticed something very strange. After I had reached my comment flagging limit for comments, and I click to flag another one, I get this:

[image]

At the bottom of the dialog it says that I have zero flags remaining, yet the message still appears. Then, after I select an option and click "Flag Comment", it gives me a message, saying that I have reached my limit for the day.

Can Stack Overflow display the limit message only and not let the dialog appear, telling the user that their flagging limit is reached? This seems to be a waste of the user's time.

Comment: `This seems to be a waste of the user's time.` --> you mean a waste of 0.5 second ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's not really my point...

Comment: This what I undestand: you want a new feature to simply avoid an extra click and a *waste* of time but at the end it's not a big deal as the whole process take less than 1 second

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's not really a "new feature", as it seems to be a bug fix.

Answer (score 4):

I don't agree about this simply because there is a small case that you forgot.

When you flag a question your are still able to open this flag pop-up in order to **retract the flag** even when you have 0 flag remaining. So if we block this pop up you will not be able to retract a flag when you reach your flag limit, thus we create another bug.

*As a side note, what you mention is not really a bug since at the end we have the correct information but later.*

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but I meant comment flags, which you can't retract.

Comment: @Xcoder In that case, the comment flag dialog behavior should also mimic the question flag behavior for consistency. Also, the limit is probably fetched only when you attempt to flag, so it wouldn't make sense to remove the dialog. Not many people max out their comment flags every day (probably just <5 users), so I don't see why developer time should be spent fixing this.